# Android, TabLayout miscalculates height, won't show bottom of layout

Tags: android, view, scroll, tabs, height

I'm working on a tab activity in my app, but it seems that the tabs are using the wrong height (thinking the layout is about half an inch taller than it is on any device) and as a result any vertical centering is off on the low side, and my scrollviews are messed up because the screen won't scroll far enough down to see the bottom of the view.  I have tried tinkering with the layout_height on any relevant class I can think of and hiding the tabs, but nothing helps and I cant find this problem anywhere else.  I generated the default template for a TabLayout activity in Android Studio 1.4.

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_youtube_searched_for_white_18dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.example.ggould.flyingfood.HistoryFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//other stuff

</LinearLayout

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Any update about this? I encountered same problem.

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to this myself. My guess is that when the fragment gets its layout parameters, the tabs aren't set yet, so it thinks it will have the full activity height minus the toolbar. But then the tabs bar gets a portion of that height and the viewpager just scrolls the fragment down a bit (which is what that `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` line seems to do). I still haven't figured out how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

On activity_main you can create a RelativeLayout. Put your ViewPager and AppBarLayout inside RelativeLayout and set your ViewPager like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

you have to wrap content for the widget.toolbar

Comment: try this , might work,,
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.example.ggould.flyingfood.HistoryFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

//other stuff

</LinearLayout

</ScrollView>

Comment: Not sure what you are suggesting here.  If it's just to make the scrollview wrap_content then I've tried that and it doesn't change anything

Comment: have you defined orientation ? if not then try so.